# SSRS Hide each row based on a value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

Hi I have created a Tablix in SSRS

```
Column A    Column B
aa  Missing
ss  result1
ee  result2
qq  Missing
rr  result3
```

I want to display only those rows(i.e only column A which are having values missing)

I tried Show/Hide based on expression

```
IIF(ColumnA.Value="Missing Data",True, False)
```

But it is not working

Answer (score 0):

IIF(ColumnA.Value="**Missing Data**",True, False)

IIF(**TextboxName**.Value="**Missing**",True, False)

you can select the target field, and check on properties what is the textbox name.